# < key triggers sticky alt on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When using a code editor like Notepad++ or Eclipse I'm experiencing a rather annoying problem:
each time I type the < key the keyboard latches into some unexpected mode whereby the subsequent keypress behaves as if the alt key were being held down. The only way to return to normal mode is to hit the escape key twice immediately after I type a < character.

The keyboard is a Microsoft Comfort Curve 2000 and the OS is Windows 7.

Does anyone have any idea what I should do to stop this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this same problem occur in other applications as well? If so, I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by system-, rather than application-specific setting:

- Double-check that you haven't enabled some Windows easy access feature, such as infamous *sticky keys* that might cause this kind of behaviour (Control Panel -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the keyboard easier to use)
- If you have additional keyboard-specific applications, such as IntelliType Pro, check settings from these applications.
- Note that your keyboard may be broken as well
- Finally the problem may be in keyboard drivers (as you noted yourself)

Comment: thanks for the ideas but sticky keys is not enabled and I don't use intelliType Pro (never heard of it). I'm going to try a different keyboard and see if it still happens.

Comment: Good point as well!

Comment: Yes, when I tried a different keyboard the problem disappears - I'm going to reinstall the MS Comfort Curve drivers and see if that helps

Comment: Its very good that you got the problem solved!